# MySQL SUM minus SUM and join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine two queries together and not sure the approach. I know very little about joins and how to work them.

I have two tables.

**users:**

```
id, 
email, 
userNumber
```

**balances:**

```
id, 
userNumber, 
credit, 
debit (multiple entries in which I use SUM - SUM group by userNumber)
```

My separate queries which work fine are below but I need to combined them somehow:

```
SELECT SUM(credit) - SUM(debit) as 'balance' FROM balances GROUP BY userNumber

SELECT u.id, u.email, u.userNumber,
g.userNumber AS groupID,
g.debit AS debit,
g.credit AS credit
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN balances AS g ON u.userNumber = g.userNumber
```

I basically need to convert the first table to have `userNumber` and balance and then use that to join the other table. Second table would not need debit or credit that would be replace with balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.userNumber,
g.userNumber AS groupID,
g.debit AS debit,
g.credit AS credit,
g.balance AS balance 
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT userNumber, SUM(credit) - SUM(debit) as 'balance' FROM balances GROUP BY userNumber) AS g ON u.userNumber = g.userNumber
```

Comment: Great simple and integrates what I already had. Had to tweak it just a bit to work, had to remove g.debt AS debt and g.credit AS credit as those weren't being called in the second select.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what exact format you want, I can suggest that you just `LEFT JOIN` your first aggregation subquery to the second one.

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.email,
    u.userNumber,
    g.userNumber AS groupID,
    COALESCE(g.debit, 0) AS debit,
    COALESCE(g.credit, 0) AS credit,
    COALESCE(t.balance, 0) AS balance
FROM user AS u
LEFT JOIN balances AS g
    ON u.userNumber = g.userNumber
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT userNumber, SUM(credit) - SUM(debit) AS balance
    FROM balances
    GROUP BY userNumber
) t
    ON u.userNumber = t.userNumber
```